# Excel VBA: find, match and copy by multiple variables

Tags: vba, excel

I’m a total beginner what comes to VBA coding, so please bear with me. The problem at hand is that I need to create an “automated” and easy to use report creation excel.

I've tried different VLOOKUP, MATCH & INDEX configurations etc. and nothing seems to work the way I need. I’ve searched and searched for a solution, but all the answers seem to be so case specific that they only brush on my issue.

> In short, I need a macro that can find, match and copy data rows *(by
>   date and product number)* from a workbook *(located in a specific
>   **source folder**)* to a new worksheet and/or workbook and save it named
>   as the search criteria *(like “productno 1-1-2017_31-1-2017.xlsx”)*

E.g. I could search all the entries for “ProductABC” between 1.1.2017 and 31.1.2017 and save the data as a new separate report file.

Products and product numbers are being stored to a sub sheet “Product list” in the report creation workbook.

**Source folder** has reports sorted by year: “…\Products\Reports\2017.xlsx” And report data is being displayed like this:

```
      A           B             C           D            E
1     Productno   Product       Attribute   Date         Time
2     123456      ProductABC    1,05        1.1.2017     10:30
3     654321      ProductCBA    1,10        1.1.2017     14:01
4     999999      ProductXYZ    1,15        3.1.2017     09:17
```

Report creation sheet looks roughly something like this:

```
       A                 B
1      Create Report
2      Starting date:    d/m/yyyy
3      End date:         d/m/yyyy
4      Product:          Dropdown list
5                        Search product data button
6                        Create report button
```

Among bunch of other failed experiments, I found this snippet of code online and tried to fiddle around with it for it to suit my needs. I know it’s not complete and probably not even close to what I need, but this is as far as I got with it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

Dim Source As Workbook
Dim Target As Workbook
Dim NewSh As Worksheet

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set Source = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2016")
Set Target = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New_report")
Set NewSh = Worksheets.Add

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Workbooks("Create_report").Activate
    FindString = Sheets("Functions").Range("C2").Value
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        Workbooks("2016").Activate
        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
            Rng.Copy Target.Range("A" & Rcount)    
            Else
                MsgBox "No products found!"
            End If
        End With
    End If

'Save Target worksheet changes:
Target.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New report 1")

‘Close workbooks
Source.Close
Target.Close

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

## **!!! UPDATE !!!**

I've made some progress with my code, here's the newest edition:

```
Sub Etsiva_click()

    'Optimazation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

'Dimensions and definitions
    'Source folder etc.
    Dim FolderPath As String, FileName As String
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\Projects\Excel\Tests\Data\"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

    'Workbooks and sheets
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook

    Dim wbok1 As Workbook
    Set wbok1 = ThisWorkbook

    Dim WSS As Sheets
    Set WSS = wbok1.Worksheets

    Dim DemPest As Worksheet
    Set DemPest = WSS("Temp")

    Dim ACtion As Worksheet
    Set ACtion = WSS("Functions")

    Dim nRows As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim CurYear As Date, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    Dim ProDuct As String

    'Count last row for product and date columns
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row And Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    'Starting row
    nRows = 3

    'Search variables
    StartDate = ACtion.Range("A2").Value
    EndDate = ACtion.Range("A3").Value
    ProDuct = ACtion.Range("A4").Value

    'Empty "Temp" sheet before pasting new data
    DemPest.Range("2:7").ClearContents

'THE Code
    'Loop folder/files
    Do While FileName <> ""
        'Open a workbook in the folder
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
     'Inner loop (below) does the copy/pasting
        Do
            If WorkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRows, 4).Value < EndDate And WorkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRows, 4) > StartDate And WorkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRows, 1) = ProDuct Then
                DemPest.Cells(nRows, 1).Value = WorkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRows, 1).Value   'Product number
                DemPest.Cells(nRows, 2).Value = WorkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRows, 2).Value   'Product
                DemPest.Cells(nRows, 3).Value = WorkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRows, 3).Value   'Data
                DemPest.Cells(nRows, 4).Value = WorkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRows, 4).Value   'Date
                DemPest.Cells(nRows, 5).Value = WorkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRows, 5).Value   'Time
                DemPest.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete      'Delete empty rows
            End If
            nRows = nRows + 1
        Loop Until nRows = LastRow + 1

        'Close the source workbook without saving changes.
        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

        'Use Dir to get the next file name.
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    'Optimization off
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

The copy part of this snippet works within one workbook/sheets, but there's been no luck when I've tried to expand it over multiple workbooks. Please help.